# Sql query for insert multiple array values into database

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm getting array value from cart table and  I want to insert cart array value into my order table but the problem I was facing is only last array value only inserting into my database but I want to insert all cart value into my order table.

```html
/*This is the form page I was getting cart value*/
<form>
<input type="text" name="cid[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="pid[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" value="3">
<input type="text" name="total[]" value="5">
</form>

/*Once the form is submited the action comes to this php page*/

<?php 
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
$pid = $_POST['pid'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$total = $_POST['cid'];

$insertquery = "INSERT INTO orders(cid,pid,quantity,total) VALUES('$cid','$pid','$quantity','$total')";

?>


/*After excution of this code only inseting the last value, not inserting the all value */
```

Comment: Iterate over arrays then.

Comment: @ u_mulder. But I'm getting form value from different name so how can I iterate it.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Answer (score 1):

Since your form elements are arrays [], loop over them like this:

```
$rowCount = count($_POST['cid']);

for($=0; $i < $rowCount; $i++) {

    $cid = $_POST['cid'][$i];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'][$i];
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $total = $_POST['total'][$i];

    // ...

}
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: And it would run faster using a Prepare Once and execute Many method

Comment: @RiggsFolly thx for reminding me to always point out injection problems if i copy/paste non-safe code from a beginner. Changed it.. IMO talking about prepare/execute in your follow up comment is off topic. Correct me if i am wrong :)